# Rails: custom drop down list for search

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I use Rails 5.1 and I have two dropdown boxes with 1) years and 2) months. Everything's working fine!

Now I want to add an option "All Months" to the months-dropdown list.

my index view:

```
<%= form_tag jobs_path, method: :get do %>
  <%= select_year(Date.today, {:prompt => "Year",:start_year => DateTime.now.year,:end_year => DateTime.now.year - 7, prefix: 'select'},{:field_name => 'year', :id => 'start-year'}) %>
  <%= select_month(Date.today, {:prompt => "month",use_short_month: true, prefix: 'select'},{:field_name => 'month', :id => 'start-month'}) %>
  <%= submit_tag("Filter Jobs", :id=>"button", :class=>"Test", :name=>"submit") %>
<% end %>
```

In the documentation of [select_month](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper/select_month) I can't see an option to add "All months".

How can I add "All month" to the months-dropdown list?

Comment: for your kind information select_month takes only 12 argument default, you can not add extra option to `all` with month, but there  may be alternative to this. but you would need to go through jquery or javescript at the time of document loaded

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can achieve this by using javascript, you need to add extra option at the time of document_loaded
here:-

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#start-month').append('<option value="all" selected="selected">All</option>');
})
```